# objectWillChange requires the types 'T.ObjectWillChangePublisher' and 'ObservableObjectPublisher' be equivalent

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am getting the error:

> objectWillChange requires the types 'ViewModelType.ObjectWillChangePublisher' and 'ObservableObjectPublisher' be equivalent

Any idea how to get around this?

```
import SwiftUI
final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject & SomeViewModelProtocol {
    @Published var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            MyView<MyViewModel>()
        }
    }
}

protocol SomeViewModelProtocol {}

struct MyView<ViewModelType: ObservableObject & SomeViewModelProtocol>: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModelType
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("")
            .onReceive(self.viewModel.objectWillChange, perform: {
                print("onReceive")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're just getting a misleading error message from the compiler. The `onReceive(_:perform:)` modifier requires a closure of one argument, but you're passing a closure of zero arguments. Try this instead:

```
        .onReceive(self.viewModel.objectWillChange, perform: { _ in
// ----------------------------------------------------------- ^^^^ add this
            print("onReceive")
        })
```